# PIC24 Timer 2/3 Interrupt Flag does not gets set

Tags: pic, timer, microchip

I am working with a PIC24FJ1024.

I want to test Timer 2/3 (32 bit timer), by writing a C code, where I toggle a pin (PORTAbits.RA7) every second.

That is part of the code:

```
while(!IFS0bits.T2IF);
LATAbits.LATA7 = ~LATAbits.LATA7;
IFS0bits.T2IF = 0;
```

When I compile and download it onto my Development Tool (Explorer 16/32), I don't see my Pin (which is connected to an LED) Toggle.

I debug program, and it turns out that `IFS0bits.T2IF` doesn't get set, the program just sits on `while(!IFS0bits.T2IF)`

Can someone explain to me why this happens?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
The Code

```
#include <xc.h>

#pragma config FWDTEN = OFF
#pragma config FNOSC = FRC //8MHz 
#pragma config ICS = PGD2

void Timer23_Init (void)
{
    /*
     Initialize T2 & 3
     from FRC
     * 1 second
     * on and off

     */

    T2CONbits.T32 = 1;//32 bit timer

    T2CONbits.TSIDL = 0;//continues through Idle Mode
    T2CONbits.TGATE = 0;//no TGATE Operationss
    T2CONbits.TCS = 0;//internal CLK SRC
    T2CONbits.TECS = 0x00;

    T2CONbits.TCKPS = 3;//1:256
    /*
      PRESCALAR = 256
     * t = 1 sec = 1000 ms = 1,000,000 us
     * Fosc = 8MHz Fosc/2 = 4MHz Tcy = 0.25 us
     * 
     * t = N*PRE*Tcy
     * N = t/(PRE*Tcy) = 1,000,000/(256*0.25) = 15,625
     * PR2 = 15625 (0x3D09)    
     */

    TMR2 = 0x00000000;
    PR2 = 15625;   

    TRISAbits.TRISA7 = 0;//output
    ANSAbits.ANSA7 = 0;//Digital
    LATAbits.LATA7 = 0;

    T2CONbits.TON = 1;
}

int main (void)
{   


    Timer23_Init ();

    while(1)
    {
        IFS0bits.T2IF = 0;

        while(!IFS0bits.T2IF);
        LATAbits.LATA7 = ~LATAbits.LATA7;
        IFS0bits.T2IF = 0;  
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code please where you setup the timer.

Comment: Sure, I just added the code right now

Comment: Have you enabled the timer interrupt. The microchip processor i recently been working with has something like 
 _T2IF = 0; <- this is a macro for resetting interrupt flag initially. 
 _T2IE = 1; -< this is a macro for interrupt enable.

Comment: T1CON = 0x00; //Stops the Timer1 and reset control reg.
TMR1 = 0x00; //Clear contents of the timer register
PR1 = 0x8CFF; //Load the Period register with the value 0x8CFF
IPC0bits.T1IP = 0x01; //Setup Timer1 interrupt for desired priority level
// (this example assigns level 1 priority)
IFS0bits.T1IF = 0; //Clear the Timer1 interrupt status flag
IEC0bits.T1IE = 1; //Enable Timer1 interrupts
T1CON = 0x8012; //Start Timer1 with prescaler settings at 1:8

Comment: Since you are polling the interrupt flag in software in your case you should be ok without enabling the interrupt.

Comment: @R.Joshi I am not doing an interrupt at the moment, it is just a loop, where the timer runs, sets T2IF, and then toggles the pin

Comment: @R.Joshi I have already done Timer 1, and It works, I am trying to work with Timer 2/3 or Timer 4/5

Comment: oh okay. Maybe my misunderstanding then. sorry! timer 1 was just an example from the datasheet. So if the interrupt is not enabled this will still trigger the interrupt flag?

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone explain to me why this happens?

The flag is almost surely firing and your led pin flipping. Except that the pin is not in GPIO mode.

Comment: Are you sure? Because I set the mode of the pin as output `TRISAbits.TRISA7 = 0`, I disabled the Analogue Pin feature `ANSAbits.ANSA7 = 0`, when I debug the program, and the debugger was stuck on `while(!IFS0bits.T2IF)`, I went to the SFR window, and changed the value of the IFS0 register to set T2IF , and suddenly the debugger could go to the next line, and toggle the Pin.

Answer (score 0):

Even though Timer2 and Timer3 work together in hardware as a 32-bit timer, I would load them as two 16-bit registers. The compiler is unlikely to know that you are treating them as a pair. I would do the same for PR2 and PR3. Also, I noticed in one similar datasheet (not the exact part number) that the interrupt for the higher timer (T3IF not T2IF) is the interrupt that will be affected, not the lower T2IF when they are concatenated.

Comment: Also, in the code i do not see anywhere where the timer interrupt is enabled.

Comment: I am not doing an Interrupt Service Routine at the moment, this code is just inside a while loop, that waits for the delay to finish and then toggles the pin.

I will try to Load PR2, and PR3 seperately, and change `!IFS0bits.T2IF` to `!IFS0bits.T3IF`

Comment: I changed the code, instead of having `PR2 = 0x3D09` I changed it to `PR2 = 0x09` and `PR3 = 0x3D`, and instead of `while(!IFS0bits.T2IF)` changed it to `while((IFS0bits.T2IF ==0) || (IFS0bits.T3IF == 0))`, I still get the same problem. I thought maybe the problem is that I didn't enable T2 or T3 interrupts, but if that is the case, how come the same example with Timer 1 worked, without adding an interrupt

Comment: Change your logical OR '||' to AND '&&'. Your 'while()' condition waits for both interrupt flags to assert, but I don't think both are supposed to assert. From the datasheet "Timer2 clock
and gate inputs are utilized for the 32-bit timer modules, but an interrupt is generated with the Timer3 interrupt flags."

Comment: I noticed in your response that you split a number which is small enough to fit entirely in PR2 (it is 16-bits wide) into two 8-bit values.  Just put 0x3d09 (or 15760 decimal) into PR2, then clear PR3 (set it to 0). Also clear both Timer2 and Timer3 16-bit registers. Here is the microchip application notes for Timer2/3 : http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39704a.pdf